# Mongo DB findAndModify query

Tags: node.js, mongodb, express, mongodb-query, findandmodify

**JSON Object:**

```
{
    "_id" : ObjectId("123"),
    "pi" : [ 
        {
            "si" : 0,
            "ui" : {
                "_id" : ObjectId("xyz"),
                "un" : "xyz",
                "his" : 27,
            }
        }, 
        {
            "si" : 1,
            "ui" : {
                "_id" : ObjectId("zyx"),
                "un" : "zyx",
                "his" : 18,
            }
        }
    ],
}
```

**Operation:**

```
db.getCollection('playing_table').findAndModify(
    {"_id" : ObjectId("123") ,"pi.ui._id":ObjectId("xyz")},
    {},
    {$inc : {'pi.$.ui.his' : 1}},
    {new : true}, 
    function (err, updata) {});
```

I want to increase *his* counter using `findAndModify()` query.

Is it possible?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming that all the `ui._id`'s are unique, this one will work for you:

```
db.getCollection('playing_table').findAndModify({
    query: { 
        "pi": { $elemMatch: { "ui._id" : ObjectId("xyz") } }
    },
    sort: {},
    update: { $inc: { "pi.$.ui.his" : 1 } }
})
```

It will result in:

```
{
    "_id" : ObjectId("123"),
    "pi" : [ 
        {
            "si" : 0,
            "ui" : {
                "_id" : ObjectId("xyz"),
                "un" : "xyz",
                "his" : 28, // incremented
            }
        }, 
        {
            "si" : 1,
            "ui" : {
                "_id" : ObjectId("zyx"),
                "un" : "zyx",
                "his" : 18,
            }
        }
    ],
}
```

Do adjust your `ObjectId`s, like for example: `ObjectId("5883ee408d4f6e2b748bf57b")`

Comment: Pleasure is mine.